# Using IF statement with Variable value as Condition in SNowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and SQL scripting. I am trying to achieve a logic to execute commands in IF statement block when a variable condition is true using Snowflake, i went to the documentation but eventually i am doing mistakes in writing code. Can you please help me in correcting it.

//Step 1:
//Declare variable
declare
CNT NUMBER;

//Step 2:
//Assigning Value to variable
begin
CNT := (Select count(*) from CLOUDMED_AI.DATAWAREHOUSE_INTEGRATION_ADMIN.SYNAPSE_TO_SNOWFLAKE_CONTROL );

//Step 3:
//Using Variable in IF statement

IF (CNT < 100)
then
Select top 10 * from CLOUDMED_AI.DATAWAREHOUSE_INTEGRATION_ADMIN.SYNAPSE_TO_SNOWFLAKE_CONTROL
end IF;
end;

But the above lines for me is throwing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that works. Different table names, but you should be able to follow the structure.

```
execute immediate $$
declare 
    RECORD_COUNT NUMBER;
    output RESULTSET; 
begin
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :RECORD_COUNT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
    IF (RECORD_COUNT<100) THEN 
        output:=(SELECT TOP 10 * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES);
    END IF;
    RETURN TABLE(output);
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir thank you for your help.
can you help me   how to use  variables in if condition which having truncate  and insert  commands in 2 different variables. Example TRuncate_sql_command := 'Truncate table tablename';
Insert_sql_command  : = 'INSERT INTO Tablename';
how can i call them in the sql store proc using above code

Comment: You are welcome! As I understand you are asking how to execute SQL statement stored in a variable. You can do it using execute immediate, e.g. 

"execute immediate Insert_sql_command;" (without quotes)